# Custom 404 with EPiServer CMS5 on IIS 6

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, http-status-code-404, episerver

I have been trying to set up a custom 404 page for several days now but still haven't succeeded.

The target system is EPiServer CMS 5 running on Windows 2003. My development system is EPiServer CMS 5 running on Windows Vista. this means I can only debug on a different version of IIS.

Anyway: The problem is that the custom 404 is displayed whenever I type in any address ending with .aspx. When the address ends with /, it is redirected to the custom 404 page ONCE... after that, I get a standard 404 error.

Does anyone have any suggestions? This is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you enable wildcard mapping in IIS. See this FAQ for more info: http://world.episerver.com/FAQ/Items/How-do-I-switch-my-developer-site-from-using-Casini-Web-server-to-IIS/